# Hold tomcat startup until jprofiler start

Tags: tomcat

How do we hold tomcat startup until jprofiler connect? I wanted to see how CPU is changing during tomcat startup. But when I connect to the tomcat process using jprofiler, tomcat startup is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start JProfiler
[image: Start window of JProfiler]

Click Attach to a locally running JVM option.

[image: Attach to a locally running JVM window]

Click the new session menu.

[image: new Session menu window]

Click new Remote Integration button

[image: Remote integration window]

Click next.

[image: Profiled JVM window]

Select JVM options as below picture.

[image: select JVM options]

Click next.

[image: select wait option]

Keep Wait for a connection from the JProfiler GUI option and Click next.

[image: provide port window]

provide a unused port and Click next.

[image: integrationFinishWindow]

Copy the line with agentPath in the current window. my one is

-agentpath:/Applications/JProfiler.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/macos/libjprofilerti.jnilib=port=8849

and click next. Now select No I will start the session later button and Click finish.

Now go to the terminal and type

export JAVA_OPTS=-agentpath:/Applications/JProfiler.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/macos/libjprofilerti.jnilib=port=8849

and run the tomcat using command from root director

./bin/catalina.sh run

now you can see it will hold with below message

JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...

Now click the attach button of top left corner menu

[image: attach button]

Now configure a profile in startup section and click ok.

Now you can see the data related to your tomcat startup